# Convert Constant Integer to Value* LLVM

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, compiler-construction, llvm

I am trying to create an IR instruction

```
store i32 0, i32* %3, align 4
```

I am using the method

```
StoreInst *CreateAlignedStore(Value *Val, Value *Ptr, unsigned Align, bool isVolatile = false)
```

to create the instruction. Since the first argument takes a `Value*`, somehow I need to convert `0` to `Value*`.

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 5):

You can use llvm::Constant for the *val, llvm Constant inherits from Value. One way to create a Constant for 0 is

```
llvm::ConstantInt::get(llvm::Type::getInt64Ty(Ctx), 0)
```

Where Ctx is context of a function you'r inserting StoreInst to

Comment: There is also convenient [`getInt32`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/IRBuilder_8h_source.html#l00307) method in the `IRBuilder` doing exactly this

Comment: Used the IRBuilder and it worked. Thank you so much. I want to learn the context thing though as I did not get it. How to get the value of Ctx and what does context mean? Again, thanks to both of you

Comment: You can get Contect from Function, BasicBlock or Module with getContext() function. As for the explanation of Context check out llvm documentation http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1LLVMContext.html